# how to send response recaptcha token to backend using axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, recaptcha

I am using [vue-recaptcha](https://github.com/AurityLab/vue-recaptcha-v3/tree/vue-v2.x) v3 on vue2 , and when I log response data of recaptcha request it is a fullfiled promise with a token and when I test it via postman and google verify api, it gets succeed.
but I don't know how to parse this promise and send the token to the Node backend using axios, my axios section doesn't work and I Get empty object {} at the backend side. anyone can help please?

```
methods: {
loginFunction: function() {
  this.$recaptchaLoaded();
  const token = this.$recaptcha('login');
  console.log(token);

  axios.post('http://192.168.27.167:3000/recaptcha',
   {
   token: token,
     })  
   .then(response => {
       }).catch(error => {
       console.log(error)
        })
```

[image: console screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

it solved by a friend of mine as below with adding Async Await to the code and then at console log I get pure token to using for verification.

```
 methods: {
   loginFunction: async function() {

  await this.$recaptchaLoaded();

  // Execute reCAPTCHA with action "login".
  const gresponse = await this.$recaptcha('login');
  console.log(gresponse)
```